Correct implementation of F-Beta score as a loss in Pytorch
I'm trying to implement the F-Beta score as a loss. As much as I know, I can't use >= or argmax() functions on the probability as it is not differentiable. Please correct me if I'm wrong.
Closest one I could was this Kaggle Notebook but it is for Multi Label and in Keras. I'm trying it out for Binary Classification in PyTorch.
Here is my code so far:
import torch
import torch.nn.functional as F

class ApproxFBetaLoss(torch.nn.Module):
   
    def __init__(self, beta:float = 1, class_idx:int = 0, eps:float = 1e-12) -> None:
        """
        Idea from:
        1. https://www.kaggle.com/code/rejpalcz/best-loss-function-for-f1-score-metric
        2. https://arxiv.org/pdf/2104.01459 (Surrogate F Beta Loss)
        
        args:
            beta: Beta controls the loss. 0 < beta < 1 favours precision and beta > 1 favours recall, beta == 1 is F-1 Score
            class_idx: Which class is Good or Bad. By default we say it's Class 0 Probability
        """
        super().__init__()
        self.beta = beta
        self.class_idx = class_idx
        self.eps = eps # for division by zero issues


    def forward(self, logits: torch.Tensor, labels: torch.Tensor):
        """
        logits: [Batch, 2-D] Logits
        labels: [Batch] 
        """
        probabilities = F.softmax(logits, dim=1) # We can use Sigmoid with 1 class too for the same

        # predictions = torch.argmax(probabilities, dim=1).float() # Is argmax differentiable? I don't think so as it'll give True/False and breaks
        predictions = probabilities[:,self.class_idx] # Class 0 Probabilities IS_BAD = CLASS_0

        # I think there might be some issue here in this calculation. To which extent is this correct?
        true_positives = (predictions * labels).sum().to(device = logits.device, dtype = logits.dtype)
        false_positives = ((1 - labels) * predictions).sum().to(device = logits.device, dtype = logits.dtype)
        false_negatives= (labels * (1 - predictions)).sum().to(device = logits.device, dtype = logits.dtype)

        precision = true_positives / (true_positives + false_positives + self.eps)
        recall = true_positives / (true_positives + false_negatives + self.eps)

        f_beta_score = (1 + self.beta**2) * (precision * recall) / (self.beta**2 * precision + recall + self.eps)

        return 1 - f_beta_score # LOSS is 1 - F_BETA_SCORE
    


logits = torch.tensor([[2, 10], [7, 3], [1, 4], [6, 5], [10, 3], [3, 10], [10, 3], [3, 10]]).to(device = "cuda:0", dtype = torch.bfloat16)
labels = torch.tensor([0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1]).to(device = "cuda:0", dtype = torch.bfloat16)

ApproxFBetaLoss(beta = 1, class_idx = 1)(logits, labels)

This gives me the loss as 0.3594 and looking at the F-1 Score from sklearn for the same, the F-1 score for Class-1 is 0.6666 which makes it the loss of 1-0.66 = 0.3333
Looks like I might be close but can someone please confirm or correct?
